# How to punctuate a sentence with post-nominal letters followed by a parenthetical fragment?

Tags: punctuation, parentheses

Here is the example:

If you have any questions, please email John Smith, Ph.D. (jsmith@email.com).

I don't think a period should follow the closed parenthesis, but the document that I was given does so.

Comment: Personally, I would write it: *Please email John Smith PhD - at jsmith@email.com.

Comment: I would do as WS2 said but if in doubt consult either *Debrett's Correct Form* or preferably, a church-Bible type *Webster's Dictionary*.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the period should go inside the parenthesis if you are in the US.

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but you need to add material to support your answer, and possibly flesh it out a bit more.  The [help center](http://history.stackexchange.com/help) has a lot of good advice on how to wrate a good answer.